# PHP txt download does not write text area contents

Tags: php, textarea

I have this form where you enter text into a text area and on submit php generates a text file which is supposed to contain the text that was entered in the text area. 
But the problem is from the code i wrote, the text file does download but has no text in it. 
So i change the text area into an input field with type text, and it returns the data in the text file, but with no line breaks. Here is my code

```
<html><body>    
<form action="download.php" method="post">
<textarea id="output" name="output"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="op" type="hidden" id="fakeop" >
<input type="submit">
</body></html>
```

And the contents of php file are

```
<?php
$filename = 'random.txt';
$somecontent = $_REQUEST["output"];
!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $somecontent);
fclose($handle);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($filename);

?>
```

if i change to $somecontent = $_REQUEST["op"];
it does return the text file with the contents. but why not when its output.?

Comment: echo $somecontent = $_REQUEST["output"]; to check you are receiving the text or not.

Comment: Do you close the form tag anywhere in the code? Also try adding  enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag after method="post".

Comment: Why aren't you using `$_POST`?

Comment: @Fred There is no need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` here, that's when you want to upload some files

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please Test the php page with below code

```
<?php
$filename = 'random.txt';
$somecontent = $_POST["output"];
!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $somecontent);
fclose($handle);

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($filename);
```

?>